# Who fired the rocket that hit al-Shifa Hospital and playground in Gaza on July 28, 2014?

Tags: israel, palestine

There are conflicting claims of who was responsible for a rocket attack on an outpatient clinic at the [al-Shifa hospital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shifa_Hospital) and a nearby playground in Gaza on July 28, 2014

The [Israeli Defence Force claimed it was Palestinian terrorists](http://www.idfblog.com/blog/2014/07/31/hamas-launches-rockets-civilians-gaza/).

[Sky News](http://news.sky.com/story/1308990/israel-blames-hamas-for-gaza-childrens-deaths) says the  Israel Defence Forces (IDF) deny responsibility, but that Gaza locals suspect the Israelis

[Aljazeera](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/middleeast/2014/07/deaths-as-israel-resumes-gaza-strikes-20147281452469626.html) and [The Blaze](http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2014/07/28/israel-denies-striking-gaza-hospital-park/) quote both sides denying responsibility and blaming the other.

Is there any objective evidence of whether the rocket(s) were launched by Hamas or by the IDF?

Comment: What side we choose to believe is irrelevant in ascertaining the facts, this is merely asking which side we believe.

Comment: One may hope that the side we choose to believe is determined by the facts. I'm expressly not interested in people's beliefs, but in the facts that convinced them (or the absence of such evidence, a valid answer too). I rephrased it so the word 'belief' is more directly disassociated with my question.

Comment: I suggest to ask again in several weeks/months when actual facts may be available to the general public.

Comment: As it is, this question is impossible to answer in this community.  Because both sides disclaimed responsibility, I can claim that it was actually an entirely unrelated natural gas explosion (or other coincidental natural explosion), or that it was a lone-wolf terrorist deliberately trying to fan the flames, and no one can disprove it.  We just don't have enough information and can't get it.

Comment: You could claim so, but I would not accept your answer for the clear reason that it would be by far the most unlikely out of all possible solutions. I don't understand why people cannot bring forth evidence and claim not the definitive yes-or-no (which you never really can) but rather attribute likeliness to a result based on evidence. The simple fact that someone discounts a claim cannot make it impossible to say something useful about the matter, otherwise I might as well claim that if I throw you out the window you will not fall.

Comment: @Spork: because the only people who have *reliable* evidence on this are extremely unlikely to be Skeptics.SE users, and even if they were they would definitely not lightly reveal such information. Otherwise you are just asking for a review of current news...

Comment: Fair enough. It feels like such a review of current news could prove insights sometimes though. Similar to how the review of news for MH17 was apparently done differently enough by Russian media than by western media, up to the point where things that were facts 2 weeks before suddenly become disputed, even if they are crystal clear. I was wondering if that happened here, too.

Comment: Related links: Finnish journalist confirms that rockets are fired *from* near the hospital (1)[http://www.algemeiner.com/2014/08/01/finnish-tv-reporter-at-gazas-al-shifa-hospital-its-true-that-rockets-are-launched-here-from-the-gazan-side-into-israel-video/]. Journalist Nick Casey apparently tweeted about Hamas being there (2)[http://dailycaller.com/2014/07/31/hamas-concealing-their-role-in-innocent-gaza-deaths-by-threatening-expelling-reporters/]

Answer (score 7):

We have a few sides to this story:

- Israeli citizens
- The Israeli Army (IDF)
- The Gazan citizens
- Hamas, the rulers of Gaza
- Independent journalists who are not Israeli or Gazan

The location in question is right in the middle of the Gaza strip and both sides would likely fire over that point. It should be noted that a significant portion of Hamas weapons, being improvised, fall short of their intended targets and land in the Gaza strip. Consider [this incident](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=66e_1403669599) in which a three year old Gazan girl was killed by a misfired Hamas rocket. **Therefore, either side could plausibly have fired the projectile which landed in Shifa.**

#### Israeli citizens

**Israeli citizens** have no evidence one way or another, they were not present so I do not see their viewpoint as being significant.

#### The Israeli army

**The Israeli army**, as party to the conflict, would be a likely suspect. The IDF denies that they fired on the hospital, and in fact [blames Hamas](https://www.idfblog.com/blog/2014/07/31/hamas-launches-rockets-civilians-gaza/). That is not surprising, I'm not sure of any incidents in which the IDF said "yes, we bombed that place that we shouldn't have".

#### Gazan citizens

**The Gazan citizens** may or may not have seen from where came the projectile, or from where it was launched. I have not seen any reports from Gazan citizens regarding this specific incident. I speculate that is because if it was an Israeli projectile, then it would have been moving too fast to see from where it came, and if it were a Hamas projectile then whoever saw the launch would not know to correlate it with the hospital, and whoever saw the explosion would have no way of knowing from where it came. I don't know if Gazan citizens would keep quiet out of fear if they knew it were a Hamas projectile.

#### Hamas

**Hamas** claims that the missile is Israeli in origin. This claim is supported by the fact that [Hamas uses the hospital as an operation center](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2014/07/31/why-hamas-stores-its-weapons-inside-hospitals-mosques-and-schools/) and [launches rockets from the hospital](http://5tjt.com/finnish-tv-reporter-at-gazas-al-shifa-hospital-its-true-that-rockets-are-launched-here-from-the-gazan-side-into-israel-video/), thus one would conclude that would make it a military target for the IDF.

#### Independent journalists

**An independent journalist** has reported that the missile which hit al-Shifa was [a misfired Hamas missle](http://dailycaller.com/2014/07/31/hamas-concealing-their-role-in-innocent-gaza-deaths-by-threatening-expelling-reporters/). However, by the same reasoning that Gazan citizens would not know who is responsible, I don't see how the journalist could conclude that Hamas was responsible. His explanation for his conclusion is `Witness: militants rushed and cleared debris` which seems tentative at best.

## Conclusion

**Either side is plausible.** People will believe that "the other side" is responsible no matter which side of the conflict they are on. With no remains of the projectile saved to be examined, we will probably never know.

## What evidence does remain

This is a late edit. I've [found](http://www.vanityfair.com/news/politics/2014/07/gaza-shifa-hospital-bombing) the following photograph which purports to be the site of the bombing. I cannot say if it is accurate or not. Perhaps someone familiar with the types of weapons used by Hamas and Israel could make an assessment.

[image: Damage done to Al Shifa hospital.]

Comment: *neither does any other army*, the USA *did* admit to [bombing the MSF hospital in Kunduz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunduz_hospital_airstrike).

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with an argument that promotes where someone was born above what evidence they have to defend their position.

Comment: @Oddthinking: I only mention the disclaimer because one could accuse me of being a biased party. I agree with you, and I hope that you find my sources unbiased. Thanks.

Comment: @gerrit: Thanks, I removed the bit that you reference.

Comment: In the absence of objective evidence, uncorroborated testimony of interested parties should be given less weight than uncorroborated testimony of uninterested parties. Assigning a rough rating to the reliability of sources is part and parcel of all the humanities (and more so of the intelligence community). Facts are good but when all you have is people's statements you have to do the best you can. This answer identifies little objective evidence and (quite reasonably) rates the testimony as ambiguous because there is no way to disambiguate the conflicting claims.

Comment: I suppose the IDF could have objective evidence in the form of radar tracking data, but if so they are keeping the details of their capabilities secret (and as polarized as the region is more than a few people wouldn't believe them anyway). Likewise, Hamas could in principle have found enough device fragments enough to identify the weapon, but there would be those who simply assume they were collected from other sites.

Comment: Two points in favor of the journalists:  Hamas rockets carry wimpier warheads than Israeli bombs, both in total power and in detonation rate.  Someone used to both could very well tell them apart.  Also, the Hamas censorship suggests that they were telling the truth.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: [This page](http://www.vanityfair.com/news/politics/2014/07/gaza-shifa-hospital-bombing) has a photo which purports to be the site of the bombing. [Direct link to image](http://media.vanityfair.com/photos/54cac4475106202708201a0b/master/w_900,c_limit/image.jpg). I cannot say if it is accurate or not. Perhaps someone familiar with the two types of weapons could comment on the damage done.

Comment: @dotancohen I'm no explosives expert but from that picture I see no shrapnel damage anywhere around and the windows on the building in the background seem unbroken.  Israel has some missiles designed not to throw fragments but they're guided and used for assassination, not for a strike on a building.  I also note the absence of concrete dust--my understanding is that this means a low detonation rate.